# Difference between using or not lambda function in python tkinter button command

Tags: python, button, tkinter

i have a question when using the Button widget in tkinter. I am new to this.
I noticed that when we use the command in the Button widget, sometimes we call a simple function just like that and sometimes we use lambda function and then we call it. What is the difference?

For example: tk.Button(window, text = "Click Me!", command = myfunction)
tk.Button(win,text="Result",command=lambda: result(en1.get())

Cant we just use it without lambda?
THank you.

Comment: If you have to pass some arguments to the function, use `lambda`.

Answer (score 2):

**Use of `lambda`:**

- The parentheses are the main reason that the function gets executed when given as `command` to a `Button` without `lambda`. If the function(which you are passing to the `Button` as a `command`) has no parameters(to be passed to itself), then you can simply pass it as a `command` avoiding the parentheses`()`. And hence you don't need to use `lambda` in this case. Like in this **Example:**`command=func`.
- So using `lambda` is only necessary when the function has its own parameters(to be passed to itself).Like in this  **Example:**`command=lambda:func(a,b,c)`

**What `lambda` Does:**

- When you have to pass arguments to the function itself you have cannot avoid `parentheses()`.
- So in the case of `buttons`, `lambda` basically delays the execution of the function until the user clicks the button, by creating another function on the spot, which does not get called until the button is actually clicked. Hence the function does not get executed, where it is given as `command` to the `Button`.

Any Questions will be answered.